# How to loop in Visual Basic 6, my FOR loop is not working

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, vb6

> Hello everyone!

I,m trying to use FOR loop in my vb6 project. In the subject there are two recordsets. First recordset find the record in MS Access database table and get some values then second recordset use these values to update in another table.
When I compile there is no error, but in the table no value update. Moreover this loop work only one time I mean it is not looping. What is wrong? Please Help!
Thanks

```
Sub UpdatePreQty()
    Dim rsTmp As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rsStock As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim tmpICODE As String
    Dim tmpBCODE As String
    Dim tmpQty As String

    For I = 1 To Val(txtTmpItemCount.Text)
        Dim strsql As String '-----Write this line only once on a form
        strsql = "SELECT * FROM [bill_details] WHERE  [bill_sno] =" & sno
        If rsTmp.State = adStateOpen Then rsTmp.Close
            rsTmp.Open strsql, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
            tmpICODE = rsTmp("prod_sno")
            tmpBCODE = rsTmp("Batch")
            tmpQty = rsTmp("qty")

            If rsStock.State = adStateOpen Then rsStock.Close
                rsStock.Open "SELECT * FROM Batch where BCODE='" & tmpBCODE & "' and ICODE ='" & tmpICODE & "' and [ccode]='" & Ccode & "'", cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
                rsStock("OUT") = (Val(rsStock("OUT")) - tmpQty)
                rsStock("CBAL") = Val(rsStock("OBAL")) + Val(rsStock("IN")) - Val(rsStock("OUT")) '
                rsStock.Update
    Next

    MsgBox "Previous stock update"
    If rsStock.State = adStateOpen Then rsStock.Close
    If rsTmp.State = adStateOpen Then rsTmp.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Change `Next` to `Next I`

Answer (score 2):

Solved with change FOR LOOP to DO WHILE

```
Do While Not rsTmp.EOF
Loop
```

Thanks to all